I am getting this error while using WhatsApp-web.js package for node.js related to 'WidFactory'
throw new Error('Evaluation failed: ' + helper_js_1.helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails));
^
Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'WidFactory')
at puppeteer_evaluation_script:2:42
at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/Users/mihirprabodhnavare/Documents/onelist/gpt/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:221:19)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (/Users/mihirprabodhnavare/Documents/onelist/gpt/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/ExecutionContext.js:110:16)
at async Client.sendMessage (/Users/mihirprabodhnavare/Documents/onelist/gpt/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/src/Client.js:888:28)
Node.js v21.6.0
I should be able to use multiple session

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
